# Feasibility of frequent day trips from USA to Mexico during a 30 day period

Tags: usa, borders, mexico

In this case I am a U.S. citizen living abroad. I will be living for a month in a rented house in southern New Mexico, near El Paso, Texas. I have never been to Mexico before but was thinking of making short trips to Ciudad Juárez during the weekends, just for sightseeing and possibly to buy groceries.

Is this feasible or, considering the current [refugee situation](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/el-paso-mayor-declares-state-emergency-over-influx-migrants-mexico-border-2022-12-18/) and perhaps possible time spent on crossing the border, a ridiculous idea? Is it common for people living near the border to cross to Mexico on a frequent basis?

Comment: I used to work for an employer that had manufacturing plants in Mexico. When I went there company policy didn't not want us to stay in Mexico over night so we took a  hotel  in the US. We crossed the border twice every day. No problem at all. That was about 15 years ago through.

Comment: @JonathanReez thanks for asking, I heard in the news a few days ago that there was an influx of refugees crossing the border near El Paso, I was wondering if the crossover point is very busy place with stricter controls than normally and maybe longer wait times.

Comment: @neo Refugees don't tend to join the lines of people crossing the border as they typically don't have any travel documents to allow them regular access into the US.  They can disrupt things, sure, but won't be a part of the actual line of people crossing the border

Comment: @neo Do you have Sentri, or Global Entry?  Or a Passport Card?

Comment: @Midavalo nope just a regular passport. But I could maybe apply for one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disclaimer - I have never crossed (in either direction) the border at El Paso / Ciudad Juárez, so this is just a general observation on crossing land borders in Mexico.  I have crossed the border hundreds of times from Tijuana.

It is quite feasible to cross the land border from the US to Mexico (and back) regularly - many people do it, a large number of them do it daily.  Both Mexican and US citizens (and to a lesser extent other nationalities).  Something like 80,000 vehicles cross from Tijuana into San Diego EVERY DAY! So yes, it's pretty common.

The longest/slowest portion of the trip will almost always be crossing from Mexico to the US, as every vehicle and person is stopped and checked.  It is typically (from my observation) easier for a US citizen as you already have the right to enter the US.  I am not a US citizen/resident, so I enter on a tourist visa, but usually have no issues other than time.

If you have Global Entry or SENTRI (possibly also NEXUS) you can skip most of the waiting as you are a "Trusted Traveler" however these cost and there are interviews and possibly a wait for both pre-approval and interview appointments.  When we got our SENTRI we waited longer than a year and that was pre-Covid which slowed things even more.  Note that if you cross by vehicle through the SENTRI/Global Entry lanes the vehicle must also be registered for SENTRI entry.

If you have a Passport Card you may be able to cross at what I believe are called READY lanes (I assume these are available into El Paso) which may or may not be quicker than a standard crossing.

If you have none of the above you'll need to cross with everybody else.  In Tijuana this is typically the slowest, and in my (pre-SENTRI) experience usually takes between 1 and 3 hours.  Sundays and Monday mornings can be much, much longer, which may be something to consider as you mention crossing on weekends, so I assume Friday night or Saturday mornings into Mexico, and then Sunday afternoon/evenings back into the US.  Everyone else is doing the same, so that's when it's the slowest!

Things to note:

- If you don't do anything stupid then you should be fairly safe.  If you get drunk or into drugs or other nefarious activities then the risk increases.  Be sensible.
- You mention buying groceries in Mexico - I assume you mean to take back into the US.  Make sure you are fully aware of what you can and can't take into the US such as meats, fruits, grains, nuts etc. as many things are banned and you can get fined (and if you're in the Trusted Traveler program you can also lose your Global Entry or SENTRI)
- It may be worth considering walking (I don't know how far away things are in Juarez though) as the pedestrian entry back into the US can be much quicker than the standard vehicle crossings

Comment: "with everybody else": is there no separate faster lane for US citizens?

Comment: @phoog I guess the READY lane is the separate lane for US citizens (they have to have a passport card or possibly an enhanced driver licence to use this lane). This lane is also used by Mexicans with a Border Crossing Card so it can have a LOT of people in it and isn't always that quick. SENTRI is better